# Errors when running Multi GPT

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have downloaded multi gpt and I am on mac. When i try to launch it using python -m multigpt  I get AttributeError: module 'lmql' has no attribute 'query'

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/capelle/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "/Users/capelle/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/Users/capelle/Multi-GPT/multigpt/__main__.py", line 8, in <module> from multigpt.multi_agent_manager import MultiAgentManager File "/Users/capelle/Multi-GPT/multigpt/multi_agent_manager.py", line 21, in <module> from multigpt import lmql_utils File "/Users/capelle/Multi-GPT/multigpt/lmql_utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from multigpt.lmql_utils._queries import generate_experts, generate_trait_profile File "/Users/capelle/Multi-GPT/multigpt/lmql_utils/_queries.py", line 4, in <module> @lmql.query AttributeError: module 'lmql' has no attribute 'query'`

and this is the file queries inside:

```
`import lmql


@lmql.query
async def generate_trait_profile(name):
    '''
    argmax(max_len=2000)
    """
        Rate {name} on a scale from 0 (extremly low degree of) to 10 (extremly high degree of) on the following five traits: Openness, Agreeableness, Conscientiousness, Emotional Stability and Assertiveness. Follow the format precisely:

        Openness: [OPENNESS]
        Agreeableness: [AGREEABLENESS]
        Conscientiousness: [CONSCIENTIOUSNESS]
        Emotional Stability: [EMOTIONAL_STABILITY]
        Assertiveness: [ASSERTIVENESS]

        Short description of personality traits of {name}:
        [DESCRIPTION]
    """
    from
        'openai/text-davinci-003'
    where
        INT(OPENNESS) and INT(AGREEABLENESS) and INT(CONSCIENTIOUSNESS) and INT(EMOTIONAL_STABILITY) and INT(ASSERTIVENESS)
    '''

@lmql.query
async def generate_experts(task, min_experts, max_experts, llm_model):
    '''
    argmax(max_len=2000)
    """
        The task is: {task}.
        Please determine which historical or renowned experts would be best suited to complete the given task. Include all experts explicitly mentioned in the task. Name between {min_experts} and {max_experts} experts. List three goals for them to help the overall task. Follow the following format precisely:
        1. <Name of the person>: <Description of how they are useful>
        1a) <Goal a>
        1b) <Goal b>
        1c) <Goal c>
        [RESULT]
    """
    from
        llm_model
    '''


@lmql.query
async def smart_select_agent(message_history, list_of_participants):
    '''
    argmax
        """Consider the following excerpt of a panel discussion :\n\n{message_history}\n
         Now consider this list of participants (ID - NAME):\n{list_of_participants}\n
         Who should talk next? Explain your reasoning. First and foremost, ensure that if
         the last speaker addresses one of the participants directly, it should be their turn next.
         Secondly, make sure each participant contributes roughly equal parts to the discussion.\n
         Reasoning: [REASONING]\n
         Therefore, the next speaker should be: [INTVALUE] - [NAME]
        """
    from
        'openai/text-davinci-003'
    where
        INT(INTVALUE)
    '''


@lmql.query
async def classify_emotion(message):
    '''
    argmax
        """Message:{message}\n
        Q: In what emotional state is the author of this message and why?\n
        A:[ANALYSIS]\n
        Based on this, the overall emotional sentiment of the message can be considered to be[CLASSIFICATION]"""
    from
        "openai/text-davinci-003"
    distribution
        CLASSIFICATION in [" agreement", " critique", " surprise", " annoyance", " neutral", " amusement", " idea", " sad"]
    '''


@lmql.query
async def create_chat_completion(messages, llm_model):
    '''
    argmax
        for message in messages:
            if message['role'] == 'system':
                "{:system} {message['content']}"
            elif message['role'] == 'user':
                "{:user} {message['content']}"
            elif message['role'] == 'assistant':
                "{:assistant} {message['content']}"
            else:
                assert False, "not a supported role " + str(role)
        schema = {
            "thoughts": {
                "text": str,
                "reasoning": str,
                "plan": str,
                "criticism": str,
                "speak": str
            },
            "command": {
                "name": str,
                "args": {
                    "[STRING_VALUE]" : str
                }
            }
        }
        stack = [("", schema)]
        indent = ""
        dq = '"'
        while len(stack) > 0:
            t = stack.pop(0)
            if type(t) is tuple:
                k, key_type = t
                if k != "":
                    "{indent}{dq}{k}{dq}: "
                if key_type is str:
                     if stack[0] == "DEDENT":
                        '"[STRING_VALUE]\n'
                     else:
                        '"[STRING_VALUE],\n'
                elif key_type is int:
                     if stack[0] == "DEDENT":
                        "[INT_VALUE]\n"
                     else:
                        "[INT_VALUE],\n"
                elif type(key_type) is dict:
                    "{{\n"
                    indent += "    "
                    if len(stack) == 0 or stack[0] == "DEDENT":
                        stack = [(k, key_type[k]) for k in key_type.keys()] + ["DEDENT", "}\n"] + stack
                    else:
                        stack = [(k, key_type[k]) for k in key_type.keys()] + ["DEDENT", "},\n"] + stack
                else:
                    assert False, "not a supported type " + str(k)
            elif t == "DEDENT":
                indent = indent[:-4]
            elif type(t) is str:
                "{indent}{t}"
            else:
                assert False, "not a supported type" + str(t)
    from
       llm_model
    where
       STOPS_AT(STRING_VALUE, '\"') and STOPS_AT(INT_VALUE, ",") and INT(INT_VALUE)
    '''`
```

I am expecting to get multigpt to launch but i get this error each time. Even with virtual environment of python 3.11

Comment: Can you provide link from where you downloaded multigpt?

Comment: https://github.com/rumpfmax/multi-gpt